# Check TimeSlot is between another Time Slot

Tags: php, datetime, logical-operators

So I have block time and appointment time
let's say block time is

```
$block_start = "13:00"
$block_end = "15:00"
```

and the appointment time is

```
$appointment_start = "14:00"
$appointment_end = "15:00"
```

now I want to check if the appointment time is between block time and vice versa

my current code

```
   $start_time = strtotime($block_time->time_from);
   $end_time = strtotime($block_time->time_to);
   if ($timeSlot_From >= $start_time && $timeSlot_To <= $end_time) {
       $staff_obj['between_block_time'] = TRUE;
   }
```

other conditions

**condition 1**

if appointment time is

```
 $appointment_start = 13:00
 $appointment_end = 16:00
```

and block time is

```
$block_start = 14:00
$block_end = 15:00
```

then also it should not allow booking

**condition 2**

if block time is

```
$block_start = 13:00
$block_end = 16:00
```

and appointment time is

```
$appointment_start = 14:00
$appointment_end = 15:00
```

**condition 3**

if appointment time is 13:00-14:00
and block time is 14:00-15:00
then appointment booking is allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So 2 times won't collide if one starts after the other one ends OR one ends before the other one starts.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function isNoCollision($t1s, $t1e, $t2s, $t2e){
    $t1s = getTimeInSeconds($t1s);
    $t1e = getTimeInSeconds($t1e);
    $t2s = getTimeInSeconds($t2s);
    $t2e = getTimeInSeconds($t2e);
    return $t1e <= $t2s || $t1s >= $t2e;
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/92d14)

So your driver code would be like:

```
<?php

if(isNoCollision(..)){
  // do something
}else{
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to test if you `$appointment_start` is is your block time and the same for `$appointmnent_end`

You can do something like this

```
$start_time = strtotime($block_time->time_from);
$end_time = strtotime($block_time->time_to);

if ($timeSlot_From >= $start_time && $$timeSlot_From <= $end_time &&
    $timeSlot_To >= $start_time && $$timeSlot_To <= $end_time) {
    $staff_obj['between_block_time'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: what is my appointment time is 13:00-16:00 and block time  is 14:00-15:00 then also it should not allow booking

Answer (score 0):

you can build 2 arrays containing 60 second slots and check, if the they have an intersection, something like that:
! some checks need to be done, eg. times need to end with 00 seconds

```
 function booking_available($start1, $end1, $start2, $end2) 
    {
        $start1    = new DateTime($start1);
        $end1      = new DateTime($end1);
        $interval1 = new DateInterval('PT60S');
        $period1   = new DatePeriod($start1, $interval1, $end1);
        $laDate1   = array();
        foreach ($period1 as $date) {
            $laDate1[] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
        
        $start2    = new DateTime($start2);
        $end2      = new DateTime($end2);
        $interval2 = new DateInterval('PT60S');
        $period2   = new DatePeriod($start2, $interval2, $end2);
        $laDate2   = array();
        foreach ($period2 as $date) {
            $laDate2[] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
    
        $laOverlap = array_intersect($laDate1, $laDate2);
        $lsEcho = 1; //true
        
        if(count($laOverlap) > 0) {
            $lsEcho = 0; //false
        }
        return $lsEcho;
    }
    echo booking_available('2022-01-01 13:00:00', '2022-01-01 15:00:00', '2022-01-01 14:00:00', '2022-01-01 15:00:00');
    echo booking_available('2022-01-01 13:00:00', '2022-01-01 16:00:00', '2022-01-01 14:00:00', '2022-01-01 15:00:00');
    echo booking_available('2022-01-01 13:00:00', '2022-01-01 16:00:00', '2022-01-01 16:00:00', '2022-01-01 17:00:00');
```