# Check Time Period from 10PM to 6AM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have this time-log entry on my mysql database.

```
TABLE: timelogs
- id
- employee_id
- in (datetime)
- out(datetime)
```

I wanted to check the entries if there times in between 10PM to 6AM.

This is to calculate the night premium for each employee.

Say a sample entry,

```
 - in: 2022-09-09 19:34:00
 - out: 2022-09-10 01:29:00
```

This should result that this time-log has the range to calculate the night premium.

How do I check it using Eloquent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check TimeSlot is between another Time Slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73497123/check-timeslot-is-between-another-time-slot)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`whereBetween`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) clause and convert the columns with date times to time format using [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function.

Here's an example assuming your model is called `Timelogs`.

```
Timelogs::whereBetween(DB::raw('TIME(in)'), array('22:00:00', '06:00:00'))
->orWhereBetween(DB::raw('TIME(out)'), array('22:00:00', '06:00:00'))
->get();
```